# Show that $Z$ is the null space of a suitable linear functional $f$ on $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $Z$ is an $n-1 $ dimensional subspace of an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ .
Show that $Z$ is the null space of a suitable linear functional $f$ on $X$ which is uniquely determined upto a scalar multiple.

let $\{x_i:1\leq i\leq n-1\}$ be a basis of $Z$.Let $x_0\notin Z$.then $\{x_0\}\cup \{x_i:1\leq i\leq n-1\}$ is a basis of $X$.

Define $f:X\to K$ by $f(x_i)=0;1\leq i\leq n-1;f(x_0)=c_0$.Is this the correct answer?

Comment: You proved one part and missed one. Namely the unicity up to a scalar multiplication.

Comment: Let $g$ be another linear functional having $Z$ as its null space.Then $g(x_i)=0;1\leq i\leq n$ then $g(x_0)=k$ say then $k=(\frac{k}{c_0})\times c_0=\alpha c_0\implies g=\alpha f$ @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: is it okay now@mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: Yes it is correct.